# RM Duplicate JSON Data with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, http, request

This seems like it should be fairly simple, but I'm stumped. Using Rails I'm generating a hash with JSON HTTP Request. I'm using JSON.parse then looping through the response using an "each" (`response.each do |river| do ... end`) loop. My question is how can I get the `siteName` element only once? I'm returning duplicate data with incomplete results. The `siteName` element is listed twice in the JSON (see sample below). The other approach, not sure its the best, is to remove the **entire hash** in the array with a conditional looking for `flow => 'n/a'`. Does this make sense? What's the best practice \ solution in this situation? Any assistance is appreciated.

Here's the `JSON` I'm parsing:
https://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&indent=on&sites=09358000,09359020,09359500,09361500,09362520,09363500&parameterCd=00060,00010&siteStatus=active

The hash getting returned.

```
[{"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER AT SILVERTON, CO.", "degree"=>"0.4", "flow"=>"n/a", "siteCode"=>"09358000"}, 
{"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER AT SILVERTON, CO.", "degree"=>"0.4", "flow"=>"25.5", "siteCode"=>"09358000"}, 
{"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER BELOW SILVERTON, CO", "degree"=>"0.5", "flow"=>"n/a", "siteCode"=>"09359020"}, 
{"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER BELOW SILVERTON, CO", "degree"=>"0.5", "flow"=>"65.1", "siteCode"=>"09359020"}, 
{"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER AT TALL TIMBER RESORT ABOVE TACOMA,CO", "degree"=>"0.5", "flow"=>"100", "siteCode"=>"09359500"}, {"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER AT DURANGO, CO", "degree"=>"5.5", "flow"=>"n/a", "siteCode"=>"09361500"}, 
{"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER AT DURANGO, CO", "degree"=>"5.5", "flow"=>"241", "siteCode"=>"09361500"}, {"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER BLW DURANGO PUMP PLANT NR DURANGO, CO", "degree"=>"5.5", "flow"=>"255", "siteCode"=>"09362520"}, {"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER NEAR CEDAR HILL, NM", "degree"=>"4.2", "flow"=>"n/a", "siteCode"=>"09363500"}, 
{"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER NEAR CEDAR HILL, NM", "degree"=>"4.2", "flow"=>"284", "siteCode"=>"09363500"}]
```

Desired Output:

```
[{"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER AT SILVERTON, CO.", "degree"=>"0.4", "flow"=>"25.5", "siteCode"=>"09358000"}, 
{"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER BELOW SILVERTON, CO", "degree"=>"0.5", "flow"=>"65.1", "siteCode"=>"09359020"}, 
{"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER AT TALL TIMBER RESORT ABOVE TACOMA,CO", "degree"=>"0.5", "flow"=>"100", "siteCode"=>"09359500"},
{"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER AT DURANGO, CO", "degree"=>"5.5", "flow"=>"241", "siteCode"=>"09361500"},
{"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER BLW DURANGO PUMP PLANT NR DURANGO, CO", "degree"=>"5.5", "flow"=>"255", "siteCode"=>"09362520"},
{"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER NEAR CEDAR HILL, NM", "degree"=>"4.2", "flow"=>"284", "siteCode"=>"09363500"}]
```

Problematic Code:

```
def process_river_telemtry(results)
temp = results.dig("value","timeSeries")

@river_telemetry = []
    temp.each do |rivers|
      siteName = {'siteName' => rivers.dig("sourceInfo", "siteName")}
      siteCode = {'siteCode' => rivers.dig("sourceInfo", "siteCode", 0, "value")}

      rivers['variable']['variableCode'].each do |vc|
        variableCode = vc['value']

        if variableCode == ENV['WATERDATA_PARAM_CODE_TEMP']
          @degree = {"degree" => rivers.dig("values", 0, "value", 0, "value")}
        end

        if rivers['variable']['variableName'] == "Streamflow, ft&#179;/s"
          @flow = {"flow" => rivers.dig("values", 0 ,"value", 0, "value")}
        else
          @flow = {"flow" => "n/a"}
        end
      end

      build = siteName.merge(@degree).merge(@flow).merge(siteCode)
      @river_telemetry << build
    end    
return @river_telemetry
end
```

Comment: This question is way to vague. Create an example with the input (the parsed json) and the desired output.

Comment: Reduce your example to the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Don't link to an external JSON resource. If you have a specific (simple and limited) example of the JSON then you **must** include it directly in your question. Additionally, you must include in your question the code that isn't working with an explanation of what is not working and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is run `#select` on the hash being returned:

```
your_array_of_hashes.select{|h| h["flow"] != "n/a"}

#=>{"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER AT SILVERTON, CO.", "degree"=>"0.4", "flow"=>"25.5", "siteCode"=>"09358000"}
#  {"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER BELOW SILVERTON, CO", "degree"=>"0.5", "flow"=>"65.1", "siteCode"=>"09359020"}
#  {"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER AT TALL TIMBER RESORT ABOVE TACOMA,CO", "degree"=>"0.5", "flow"=>"100", "siteCode"=>"09359500"}
#  {"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER AT DURANGO, CO", "degree"=>"5.5", "flow"=>"241", "siteCode"=>"09361500"}
#  {"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER BLW DURANGO PUMP PLANT NR DURANGO, CO", "degree"=>"5.5", "flow"=>"255", "siteCode"=>"09362520"}
#  {"siteName"=>"ANIMAS RIVER NEAR CEDAR HILL, NM", "degree"=>"4.2", "flow"=>"284", "siteCode"=>"09363500"}
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you. @river_data = response.select{|h| h["flow"] != "n/a"}

Answer (score 0):

If the only incomplete result is the `flow` field, then you can just filter it out using

`response.reject { |h| h['flow'] == 'n/a' }`

otherwise, if you can receive any other field with `'n/a'` and this is the only form of incomplete data, then filter it iterating over the fields of the hash like

`response.reject { |h| h.map { |k, v| v == 'n/a' }.include?(true) }`